# RewriteCond not working on force https for HTTP_HOST

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I am trying to write a condition that will force https on the live host name(domain.com), but not if it's on our local testing host name (domain.local).

Here is what I have:

```
#force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain\.local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This condition rewrites to https but also redirects domain.local to domain.com

I've also tried this condition in place of the middle condition which doesn't do anything on .local or .com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
```

Here is the complete contents of my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#force ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

#rewrite payments subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^payments\.domain\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://otherdomain.com/dmi_domain.htm [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^payments\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://otherdomain.com/loanadmin/dmi_domain.htm [NC,R=301,L]

#agents folder to subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^agents\.domain\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^agents/(.*)$ /agents/$1 [L,P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^agents\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^agents/(.*)$ /agents/$1 [L,P]

#force www for .com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^payments\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^agents\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.local
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/questions/
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#force www for .local
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^payments\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^agents\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/questions/
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rate-panel/xml/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/questions/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

#get rid of index.php in url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/questions/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your bottom `http->https` rule to the top of your .htaccess just below `RewriteBase /` line. Also use this slightly modified rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !local [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. Nothing happens on either .com or .local.

Comment: Can you update your question with out latest .htaccess? Is this some kind of PHP/CMS framework?

Comment: Htaccess updated. The site is on the codeigniter php framework. thanks!

Comment: ok rule looks fine. Is it possible that CI is forcing it back to `http://`? Can you run your request in Firebug and see what redirections you get in Net tab.

Comment: I meant to add that if i remove the condition the redirect works fine, but it redirects both .local and .com to https.I don't see any redirects in the Net tab, but I don't know exactly where to find the redirects.

Comment: Your suggetion to move the https rule to the top saved my day! Many thanks! Can you please help me to understand why this rule must be the first?

Comment: Didn't solve to me, looks the problem it's with %{HTTPS} variable. Alternatives?

Comment: @giovannipds `%{HTTPS}` is standard Apache variable. You may be behind proxy or firewall. Check server documentation from your hosting providers.

Comment: Yes, but I've figured out right now that the problem is with my hosting server (I've compared the same codes on two different servers). Anyway, I'm still looking for an alternative. Best regards.

Comment: In my case I needed to use RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on. So the environmental variable mentioned below and specifically '!=on' instead of 'off'.

Answer (score 10):

You may use 
`RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off`

some time https flag not working . Don't know why. But I have found a solution to use ENV:HTTPS . This stop redirect loop for me.

Comment: It's not for all time work. anyway, did you found your proper solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably. Sorry if I haven't posted anything about it, I was focused. Thank you anyway for your attention.

Comment: Do you have still problem?

Comment: No, not anymore. Thanks mate.

Comment: In my case I needed to use RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on ('off' did not work in my particular environment).

Answer (score 0):

As many state, sometimes only *RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on* works